# The meaning of "сome + noun/gerund"

Tags: word-usage, phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

What is the meaning of this construction in the following sentence heard in [this video](https://youtu.be/ijmnkz_1Mvc?t=118)?

> DA's office is pursuing this as a capital case, which means that **come
>   sentencing** it will be up to the jury to decide [his] punishment...

Is this a short version of **`when it comes to`** or a separate instance of **`to come`** usage with the same meaning? That is **`when the sentencing time comes...`**

Comment: It’s a mistake; it should say _come sentencing_, which does indeed mean ‘when the sentencing comes’.

Comment: @Janus Bahs Jacquet thank you, the mistake must be mine, although it did sound like ***comes*** to me

Comment: It can be hard to tell the difference when the following word begins with an s; in other cases like [_come rain or shine_](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/come-rain-or-shine), it’s clearer that there’s no s. Several dictionaries, like [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/come#Preposition), for example, call this use a preposition, which I’m not convinced is right; but it is definitely a sort-of-preposition-like frozen use of what was originally, I’m guessing, a subjunctive form.

Comment: @Janus Bahs Jacquet thank for the reference, you've sufficiently answered the question so should you post a formal answer i'll gladly accept it